# How to correctly create a weak reference to method reference in Java

Tags: java, lambda, javafx, weak-references

I want to register a JavaFX `ListChangeListener` to an `ObservableList`. However I noticed, that under certain circumstances the Listener is not getting called.

**(1)** If the Listener is a method reference, everything works:

```
// using a direct method reference:
private final ListChangeListener<String> listener = this::listDidChange;

/* ... */
public void init() {
    list.addListener(listener);
}
```

**(2)** If however the Listener is a weak ref to the same method, the listener is NOT invoked:

```
// using a weak method reference:
private final ListChangeListener<String> listener = new WeakListChangeListener<String>(this::listDidChange);

/* ... */
public void init() {
    list.addListener(listener);
}
```

**(3)** Now the really funny part is, that this is working again, even though it should be the same as the previous example:

```
// direct method reference wrapped into a weak ref later:
private final ListChangeListener<String> listener = this::listDidChange;

/* ... */
public void init() {
    list.addListener(new WeakListChangeListener<String>(listener));
}
```

Two questions:

- What exactly happens, when a weak ref to a method ref is created?
- What is the difference between (2) and (3)?

Comment: According to the JavaDoc for WeakListChangeListener: "Note: You have to keep a reference to the ListChangeListener, that was passed in as long as it is in use, otherwise it will be garbage collected to soon."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Creating a method reference (in this case) is just like creating any other object. So if we replace it with a `new` expression, example 2 becomes like:

```
private final ListChangeListener<String> listener = new WeakListChangeListener<String>(new Foo());

public void init() {
    list.addListener(listener);
}
```

Whereas example 3 would be:

```
// direct method reference wrapped into a weak ref later:
private final ListChangeListener<String> listener = new Foo();

public void init() {
    list.addListener(new WeakListChangeListener<String>(listener));
}
```

Now the difference becomes fairly obvious:

1. In example 2 the newly created instance of `Foo` is instantly eligible for garbage collection, as nothing holds a strong reference to it.
2. In example 3 you keep a strong reference to the newly created `Foo` object in your `listener` field, so it will only be collected when the object with the `listener` field is collected.

**P.s.:** If method references in Java really were references to methods, meaning that methods were first-class objects in their own right (like in Javascript), example 2 would work too as every object would implicitly hold a reference to all their methods.

Comment: It’s important to emphasize that even the fixed version depends on the reachability of the surrounding object (the one with the `listener` instance field). In principle, an optimizing JVM can eliminate entire object graphs if their only root references are local variables. This would even apply if “method references in Java really were references to methods” and demonstrate, that it is not a good idea to allow something unpredictable as garbage collection to alter the semantics of a program (i.e. whether an event handler will be invoked).